# Jquery thumbnail buttons not working

Tags: jquery, image

I want to change a larger picture by clicking on a thumbnail. For whatever reason, it's not working. I have no clue what I am doing wrong and I have wasted too much time for something so simple. Thanks for looking:

**HTML - Head.php**

```
.......
 <section>
<img id="theImage" src="images/mods/angiograph/head/Ag1.jpg" title="Ag-01" alt="Ag-01">
</section>
<section id="rightMenu">
    <div id="addHolder">
        <h3 class="topHeader"><a href="#">Quick Pick</a></h3>
            <div id="quickPick">
                <ul id="thumbList">
                </ul>
            </div>
</section>  

......
```

**JS - Located at end of Body**
*The substring() was called because the src for the thumbnail was created dynamically using the imageList function (see imageProvider.js) Because these files are stored in a subdirectory there is a period in front of the root directory, which needs to be removed for the source in the Head.php file* Confused yet?

`

```
<script>
   window.onload = imageProvider.initLinks;
   $(document).ready(modUI.modAccord);

$(".Agthumb").click(function(){
    var location = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#theImage").attr("src", location.substring(1));
    });
 </script>
```

**JS - imageProvider.js**

```
 var imageProvider = {
thisPic: 0,

initLinks: function () {
    imageProvider.imageList(14, 2);
    document.getElementById("nextPic").onclick = imageProvider.processNext;
    document.getElementById("prevPic").onclick = imageProvider.processPrev;

},


multiDimensionArray:function (rows, columns) {
    var myArray = new Array(rows);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        myArray[i] = new Array(columns);
        for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = "";
        }
    }
    return (myArray);
},

imageList:function (qty, data) {
    var imageData = imageProvider.multiDimensionArray(qty, data);
    var filePath = './images/mods/angiograph/head/';
    var imgPrefix = 'Ag';
    var imageType = '.jpg';


    for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
        imageData[i][1] = filePath + imgPrefix + (i + 1) + imageType;
    }

   for (var j = 0; j<imageData.length; j++){
            $("<li>", { html:"<img class='"+ imgPrefix + "thumb' alt='"+ imgPrefix + (j + 1) + "' src=" + imageData[j][1] + " width='75' height='75'/>"}).appendTo("#thumbList");
    }

}
};
```

I don't think the css is relevant for this post, but I have no problem posting it. Just let me know! Thanks again.

Comment: what part isn't working. you've verified its calling the function? is it showing a js error? when you inspect the dom, is the source different? What does the data look like for atlasImageList? is it really a property at index [0]?

      src = imageProvider.atlasImageList[imageProvider.thisPic][0];

Comment: @flavorScape I apologize for not being clear. My brain is fried from trying to tack the problem. I am not sure, but I don't think the click function is being called. It doesn't pull up anything in the firefox error console. I am using PHPStorm, but I haven't figured out how to debug yet. I updated the imageProvider.js above. I had a couple of functions in there that were old. Everything works great in the imageProvider object. The thumbnails load with the correct dynamic information. It seems like it stops working in the script at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the selection runs first `$('.Agthumb')` before the thumbnails are generated (they are generated on window.onload event). In your code, `$('.Agthumb').length` will return zero. The click handler is not bound to any element.

You can fix this by using jQuery's `.on()`. The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HMPjP/

```
// Used on() to bind click event on thumbnails created
// by imageProvider
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#thumbList').on('click', '.Agthumb', function() {
          console.log('I was clicked');
          var location = $(this).attr("src");
          $("#theImage").attr("src", location.substring(1));
      });
});
```

Comment: You are very right! I finally came across this after deciding to reorganize where my javascript placement was. I also learned about defer. Until know I just assumed I should put $(document).ready on all of my scripts! I have no idea where I got that idea, but it was very, very wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If $ = document.getElementById

so, the question I would have then is why are there periods and a pound sign in the usage?

so, shouldn't this

```
$(".Agthumb")
```

be: `$("Agthumb")`

Comment: `$` is not equivalent to `document.getElementById`. `$(".Agthumb")` will grab a collection of jQuery objects with the class `Agthumb`. `$("Agthumb")` on the other hand will grab `Agthumb` elements, which do not exist. Have a look at [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: As @zhihao was saying, I am using it as a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Comment: there is a key word there people "IF"